# How to record time two objects are in proximity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using unity to make a simulation in which multiple game objects will move around, and depending on how long they are 2 of them in proximity something else will happen.

Now i managed to collect all of the game object into a list and i used a foreach to compare distance between each on of them.

next step is creating a variable or something to record how long are they in contact, and this is where I struggle. I created a variable called proximityCounter for this but that doesn't seem to work. It should record individual time between each pair of agents.

here is my code

```
void Update()
    {
        var Agents = FindObjectsOfType<Agent>();
        StartCoroutine(RunGameCycle(agents));
    }
    IEnumerator RunGameCycle(Agents[] agents)
    {
        foreach (Agent agent in agents)
        {
            if ((Vector3.Distance(agent.transform.position, transform.position) <= proximityThreshold))
            {
                proximityCounter++;
                //Do stuff
            }   
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(gameTick);
    }
```

This is not working I guess because first the agent is comparing distance between himself and himself, it also runs very fast I set gameTick to 1 second, but it runs very fast.

I have just started with unity a couple of months ago, so let me know if I'm missing anything or if you need more info.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It also runs very fast I set
> gameTick to 1 second, but it runs very fast.

That is the case, because you call the IEnumerator each frame. Sure it has a 1 second delay but in that 1 second delay you called 60 or more new instances of that IEnumerator.

> Next step is creating a variable or something to record how long are
> they in contact, and this is where I struggle.

I would advise you to count the Time in the Update Method for each Agent.

---

To do that we first edit the Global class that gets all the agents. First of all I would get all the agents in the Start Method so you don't have to update them each frame. (Only works if the amount of agents doesn't change while the game is running, if they change in runtime I would update the list when you created a new agent.)

Then we check in global if the Distance is lower than the proximity Threshold and if it is we start counting the time for that agent.

**Global Class:**

```cs
List<Agent> agents = new List<Agent>();
void Start(){
    agents = FindObjectsOfType<Agent>();
}

void Update() {
    // Only update it each frame when it changes in runtime
    // var agents = FindObjectsOfType<Agent>();
    
    foreach (Agent agent in agents) {
        if ((Vector3.Distance(agent.transform.position, transform.position) <= proximityThreshold)) {
            agent.EnteredProximity();
        }
        else {
            agent.LeftProximity();
        }
    }
}
```

To count the time we need to define the Function we called earlier these function mainly set a Boolean, which when true makes it so that we start counting.

If you want to do something with the amount of time until the agent left we need to do that in the Left Proximity Function.

**Agent Class:**

```cs
float time = 0f;
bool proximity = false;

void Update() {
    if (proximity) {
        // Add the difference of the last time the update method has been called
        time += Time.deltatime;
    }
}

public void EnteredProximity() {
    proximity = true;
}

public void LeftProximity() {
    proximity = false;
    // Do something with the Time Agent was in the proximity of another agent
    Debug.Log(time);
    // Resetting time
    time = 0f;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that answers it. I will try that at the soonest. I also though about instantiating a "proximity" object that could hold the time of the connection and control the two agent that created it.

Answer (score 0):

I didin't test it but...

For proximity check you could use collision with [trigger](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-isTrigger.html), to count time of proximity start time on [OnTriggerEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) and stop time OnTriggerExit. Then you could do something like this in every object (I didn't chceck/compile code):

```
public class ProximityTimer : MonoBehaviour
{
   Hashtable timers = new Hashtable();

   private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
   {
       timers.Add(other, Time.time);
   }

   void Update()
   {
       foreach( KeyValuePair<Collider,float> kvp in timers)
       {
           var currentTime = timers[kvp.Key];
           // here you check actual times of proximity
       }
   }    

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (timers.Contains(other))
        {
           var time = Time.time - (float)timers[other];
           // you can report final time here
           timers.Remove(other);
        }
    }
}
```

of course every proximity will be reported twice :)

Comment: This probably won't work as intended because around half of the many agents would need to have IsTrigger active. But if they have IsTrigger active they won't cause OnTriggerEnter with other agents that have IsTrigger active. And agents that don't have IsTriggerActive will have a much higher hitbox then needed and collide with objects even if they are far away.

Comment: I thought about two colliders in agent, one bigger as trigger and one as simple collider, but maybe this is wrong idea.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'm actually using the collision in controlling the agents movement, which begs the question, can objects have more than one collision object?

Comment: They can but it just ends in problems most of the time, mainly because collision would still need to work and colliders start triggering each other and I personally find using the proximity check much cleaner. Especially because you can just change the variable and the proximity increases instead of making each collider on each agent bigger.